# Batch script to rename and move files

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I have a radio management system which is capable of running batch scripts after shows.

I'm looking for a batch script file that renames any file in the directory like so:

> 1.mp3 --> [Replay]1.mp3

And then move the file from folder a to folder b.

Any thoughts on how do i go about creating such script in a syntax level?

Comment: Which bit are you stuck with? Creating a batch file in an editor? Finding the files? Renaming/Moving the files? Running the batch file?

Comment: I'm stuck with how to write such script file...i'm new to batch script and dont know the syntax

Comment: Read http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm and try again :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
ren *.mp3 [Replay]*.*
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you request, this script does that by searching all `mp3` files in the current folder and move them to `folderb` specifying a new name.

```
@ECHO off

FOR %%i IN (*.mp3) DO (
  MOVE "%%i" "folderb\[Replay]%%i"
)
```